# How can I include javascript in content loaded with jquery using $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load some HTML which include a bit of javascript, using jQuery. I've tried using both load() and ajax(). The HTML is inserted nicely into the DOM, but any script-tags seems to be filtered out. If I alert() the returned HTML, the scripts are included, but when i use html() or append(), the scripts are missing.

Any ideas?

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using? In 1.2+, the evalScripts() method should be done automatically

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`$.getScript`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getScript) to load and execute remote Javascript:

> Loads, and executes, a local
>   JavaScript file using an HTTP GET
>   request.

Example:

```
$.getScript("test.js", function(){
  alert("Script loaded and executed.");
  $('#myDiv').load('some.html');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
$.get("url.php",{param1:'1',param2:'2'},function(result)){
    $('#somediv').html(result);
}
```

p.s. please use the latest jquery version